# Any ideas to troubleshoot a error message on Google Map API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an API key from Google Maps where I have enabled Maps JavaScript API and GeoCoding API.

I have two options so the users can locate themselves on the map. The first one, which is upon click, works well. However, the second option, which requires a user input does not work, I keep getting the following error:

This API key is not authorized to use this service or API.

Does anyone have experience this before? Do you think I might need to enable any other APIs related to Google Maps.

Here is the class where I call the API. First part is the class and the second a function that deals with the user input.

````
export async function getCoordsFromAddress(addressInput) {
  const urlAddress = encodeURI(addressInput); 
  const response = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${urlAddress}&key=${googleApiKey}`)
  if(!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch address. Please try again!'); 
  }
  const data =  await response.json(); 
  if(data.error_message) {
    throw new Error(data.error_message); 
  }

  const coordinatest = data.result[0].geometry.location; 
  return coordinatest;
}

async fetchAddressHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const addressInput = event.target.querySelector('input').value;
    if(!addressInput || addressInput.trim().length === 0) {
      alert('Invalid Address! Try Again'); 
      return; 
    }
    const feedBackMessage = new FeedBackMessage('loading-modal-content', 'Loading location - Pleasewait');
    feedBackMessage.show();
    try {
      const coordinates = await getCoordsFromAddress(addressInput); 
      console.log(coordinates); 
      this.findPlace(coordinates);
    } catch (error) { 
      alert(error.message); 
    }
    feedBackMessage.hide(); 
  }```

Thanks!
````

Comment: It means you are using a service that is not authorized for the key you are using.  [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages).  What does your code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Based solely on what you have described, I bet you enabled Geolocation API but need to enable Geocoding API instead.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much. Here is part of the code:

Comment: @geocodezip, I have added part of the code in the original message. Also, I have geocoding and Maps JavaScript.

Comment: Is it the part of the code that works or the part with the issue?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip yes, this is the only part of my code that uses the geocoding API. You can see that in the async fetchAddressHandler() I'm calling getCoordsFromAddress(); 

I have a const that stores the google ApiKey. I console.log() the const response and the key shows correctly too.. thanks!

Comment: You need a key restricted by ip address for the web service version of the geocoder, likely why you are getting that error.  From javascript on the client, best to use the geocoder in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 and restrict the key with a URL (which is how I suspect your key is restricted, but you didn't provide that information in your question).

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, I went through my project apis and turned out I didn't add  the gecoding api restriction inside the API key, so this is why it wasn't working. I now have a key where I enabled geolocation, Map JS API and geocoding so it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "This API key is not authorized to use this service or API" error message is pretty much exactly what it says on the tin - you need to enable an additional API.

My guess would be the Places API.

If that doesn't work, you could contact Maps tech support on Monday - it's free if you have a working Google API project.

Answer (score 0):

- Please Visit : https://console.cloud.google.com/ Here Go to API Library
- Search API "Geocode" and enable the service
- If still you face error , you need to enable billing for this

[GeoCode Reverse API Enable needs Billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0Kk.png)